# How to perform a SUR with Panel Data?

Tags: seemingly-unrelated-regressions

To do a `sureg` in Stata I was thinking of

1. `reg healthy x1 x2 ... i.year i.country`
2. `reg pensions x1 x2 i.year i.country`
3. Verify if both regressions are "ok" = verify errors, variables' significance , etc.
4. If everything is okay with both regressions, I will do the `sureg` command  (SUR).

Am I wrong? Or should I do directly the `sureg` regression, and verify through that regression the coefficients' significance?

Resume of the question : do I have to do two 2-way-fixed effects model first (for 2 dependent variables), verify everything as if they were going to be always independent, and finally estimate the SUR?

I also posted this question on Statalist.

Comment: There's a statistical question embedded here, but I think in presupposing that readers recognise and understand Stata syntax the question is rendered off-topic. If you can rewrite the question without presupposing that, it would be a better fit here.

Comment: You should give explicit cross-references to other posts, not presume that people will search for them. The allusion is to http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1344598-two-way-fixed-effects-model-sur-and-some-problems #15